# What is the current status of 2d and 4d Yang-Mills as a functorial QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, category-theory

I am looking for the current status of YM, in specific 2d and 4d Yang-Mills, described as a functor. As far as I understand the issue resides in defining the propagator functorially but I have not been able to find any progress on this.